# Postgresql 9.2 "invalid locale name" on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, ubuntu-12.04

Today I installed Postgresql 9.2 on Ubuntu precise via apt.postgresql.org – all was relatively painless until I got stuck in a "invalid locale name: it_IT.utf8" error:

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# sudo -u postgres psql -Xc "CREATE DATABASE test TEMPLATE template0 ENCODING 'utf8' LC_CTYPE='it_IT.utf8'"
ERROR:  invalid locale name: "it_IT.utf8"
```

I did run `locale-gen it_IT.utf8` though, and in fact:

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_GB.utf8
en_US.utf8
it_IT.utf8
POSIX
```

Logs don't seem to have any meaningful information on why postgres isn't recognizing it_IT.utf8... can you help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If PostgreSQL hasn't been restarted after the new locale has been created, that would be the reason. `service postgresql restart` should suffice.

This is presumably due to how locales are implemented in Linux `libc`. The new locales don't get seamlessly imported into the environment of already running processes.

Comment: This is much less brutal solution than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

`local-gen` didn't work in my case.

I installed the missing locale with this:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then it showed in `locale -a`:

```
locale -a
```

And then restarting postgresql:

```
service postgresql restart
```