# Restoring Postgres 8.3 dump in 8.4

Tags: postgresql

I need to move a PostgreSql database from 8.3 Windows to 8.4 running on Linux (Ubuntu Server 12.04).

The restore aparently is ok, but when I try to show data in my program I get an error saying that some characters are not supported on WIN1252 encoding.

The original database has this properties:

Encoding: WIN1252
LC_CTYPE: English_United States.1252
LC_COLLATE: English_United States.1252

I can restore the database using LC_CTYPE = "C" and LC_COLLATE = "C", this way I get the unsupported characters in my program.

If I try to create the database using this command:

```
createdb -h 127.0.0.1 \
--encoding=WIN1252 \
--lc-ctype='English_United States.1252' \
--lc-collate='English_United States.1252' \
-T template0  -U postgres mydb
```

I get this error:

```
createdb: falló la creación de la base de datos:
ERROR:  el nombre de configuración regional «English_United States.1252» no es válido
```

First of all, how can I let my O.S. include this regional configuration?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows-1252 character set is known in Ubuntu by its other name `CP1252`.

Generally no corresponding locale is installed by default on Ubuntu because Unix folks prefer `iso-8859-15` or `utf-8`.

However the charmap should be provided by the `locales` packages. Assuming this package is installed, you may issue a command like this to create the relevant locale:

```
sudo localedef -f CP1252 \ 
               -i /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US \
               /usr/lib/locale/en_US.CP1252
```

Then run `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart` for postgres to pick up the new locale, avoiding [Postgresql 9.2 “invalid locale name” on Ubuntu 12.04](https://serverfault.com/questions/491237).

Then you should be able to run `createdb` like you did in the question except for the locale name which is `en_US.CP1252` instead of the Windows-ish `English_United States.1252`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that allowed me to create the database without issues. Now I have a new problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/542448/invalid-byte-sequence-for-character-encoding-0x00-after-upgrading-from-8-3-to-8