# Invalid byte sequence for character encoding 0x00 after upgrading from 8.3 to 8.4

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to upgrade a database from PostgreSql 8.3 to 8.4, I backed up the data from 8.3 and restored from 8.4 without issues, but, when I try to use the same program that is working perfectly connected to 8.3, it throws the error:

```
Invalid byte sequence for character encoding <<WIN1252>>: 0x00
```

Does anyone know what can be happening?

Comment: Please post your resolution as an answer and mark it accepted when you're able.  You may even [earn a badge for self answering](http://serverfault.com/help/badges/14/self-learner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pg 8.4 is more strict when dealing with characters, hence the error. It was my program that was trying to insert \0 on a field. This forced me to debug my program and solve the problem.